# How to point phpmyadmin to same databases used in MySQL

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin

I installed mysql-server on Ubuntu 18.04 and then installed phpmyadmin. The issue I have now is when I do `show databases` in mysql, I get a different set of databases from what is shown in phpmyadmin.

How do I point phpmyadmin to the correct database?

Comment: Connect to the same database hostname with the same user and you should get the same list. If you're seeing different ones, you're either connected to the wrong server, or you're using a user with different privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then you're either using different credentials and/or logging onto different Mysql servers, check with the mysql query `select @@HOSTNAME;` and/or `select USER();` and update either you PHPMyAdmin config or your ~/.my.cnf accordingly.

Comment: What's the path to the phpmyadmin config?  I'm in /etc/phpmyadmin and there are several config files.

Comment: Please Read the fine manual https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html

Comment: Ah okay, the file is /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php.  The issue was during setup I used the default `phpmyadmin` user.  Switched it to a user with permission and it restored access.  Thanks!